# Attempting to upgrade to Zend Server 6.0.1

Tags: zend-server, selinux

I am currently running Zend Server 5.6.0 (PHP 5.3) on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

I am looking to upgrade to Zend Server 6.0.1 but whether I try it automatically (through the install_zs file) or manually (editing the /etc/yum.repos.d/zend.repo) I get the same message.

```
# yum update
...
Error: Package: zend-server-php-5.3-6.0.1-662.x86_64 (Zend)
           Requires: /usr/sbin/semanage
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am reluctant to use --skip-broken as I feel it would cause issues.

I will point out that SELinux is installed on the server, but is disabled. I verified this by editing the /etc/selinux/config file.

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

The file /usr/sbin/semanage does not exist. The digging around I've done to find out why has led me to install SELinux, however it is installed and of the latest version.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like upgrading zend-server-php requires SELinux installed and working, probably because of changing selinux rules after upgrading.

Try following steps:

1. set premisibe mode of selinux, (SELINUX=premissive)
2. let the type targeted (SELINUXTYPE=targeted)
3. enable selinux (SELINUX=enabled)
4. reboot
5. upgrade your system
6. switch the SELinux off, if you do not want to use it

Comment: I edited /etc/selinux/config and set SELINUX=permissive then rebooted the server but I received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment on the previous post [it seems SELinux isn't as simple as turning it back on](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html)

After following these instructions I still received the same error, so I attempted to [install semanage](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-install-semanage-selinux-command-rpm), however I could not replicate the process.

I ended up putting a support ticket in to the hosting company who managed to install semanage.

Zend Server 6.0.1 now installed!